# Spec R is irreducible

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

A topological space is called *reducible* if $X=X_1\cup X_2$ for two closed subsets $X_1,X_2$ with $X_1\ne X\ne X_2$. Otherwise its called *irreducible*, want to show that $\text{Spec}(R)$ is irreducible if and only if the radical ideal $\sqrt{(0)}$ is a prime ideal.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way is to use the fact that irreducible components of the spectrum of a ring correspond to the minimal primes in the ring, see the [Stacks Project](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00ER) .

Answer (score 1):

This is standard, if $Spec(R)$ is not irreducible then it is the union of two closed subsets, namely two sets of the form $V(p)$ and $V(q)$ for some prime ideal $p,q$. In this case the radical $\sqrt{0}$ cannot be a prime ideal since any two elements from $V(p)*V(q)$ would result in $0$. For the other implication, if $\sqrt{0}$ is prime, then $Spec(R/\sqrt{0})$ is isomorphic to $Spec(R)$. But we know $R/\sqrt{0}$ is an integral domain so $Spec(R/\sqrt{0})$ must be irreducible.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: you said SpecR reducible implies that rad(0) in not prime that is equivalent to rad(0) prime implies SpecR irreducible, but the other implication you are talking about is the same as this!!

Comment: I don't really know what you are talking about.

Comment: @user32240 I mean it seems you proved the same implication twice.

Comment: I see. Your objection is I did not prove that if $Spec(R)$ is irreducible, then $rad(0)$ is prime. I will leave that as an exercise for you.