# Reduced and integral rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit. Are the following true?

1. If $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ is irreducible i.e, cannot be written as union of two proper closed subsets, and $R$ is reduced, then $R$ is integral domain.

Conversely,

2. If $R$ is integral domain, then $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ is irreducible.

---

The problem is equivalent to showing that $(0)$ is a prime ideal, this seems to follow but I don't see how. I think for 2. we have $\operatorname{Spec}(R) = V(\{0\}) =\overline{\{0 \}}$.

Comment: By ‘$R$ is integral’, I suppose you mean $R$ is an integral domain?

Comment: Yes, I will add that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is irreducible, it has a single minimal prime ideal, and the intersection of the minimal primes is the nilradical.
2. Your argument is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Part 1 is an if and only if. This question [Spec R is irreducible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328038/spec-r-is-irreducible)
shows that $Spec(R)$ is irreducible if and only if the nilradical $N$ is a prime ideal. So $R/N$ is an integral domain, but $R=R/N$ since $R$ is reduced.